# subprocess.run([‘cmd’, ‘args’]) returns FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

While coding an os extension with the “subprocesses” package, the FileNotFoundError seems to be re-occuring.

My code:

```
perm = “filename1 filename2”
subprocess.run(‘ren’, perm)
```

This returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    listeningfunc()
  File "main.py", line 37, in listeningfunc
    mv(listening.split(' ', 1)[1])
  File "main.py", line 16, in mv
    subprocess.run(['ren', perm])#, cwd=(os.getcwd()), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ren‘
```

I tried using

```
subprocess.run([’ren’, perm], cwd=(os.getcwd()), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

which seemed to resolve the issue (removes the error) but the function does not run. Can anyone help me with this? I’ve noticed that the package os also has similar issues.

Using OS package does not result in an error, but results in:
`sh: 1: ren: not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `ren` is a cmd built-in. Several options:

```
perm = “filename1 filename2”
subprocess.run(‘ren’, perm, shell=True)
```

or prepend with `cmd /c`

```
perm = “filename1 filename2”
subprocess.run(['cmd','/c',‘ren’, "filename1","filename2"])
```

or way better: use native os functions as it's not worth to call `ren` when you can call `os.rename`

```
os.rename("filename1","filename2")
```

another way with `shutil`

```
shutil.move('filename1','filename2')
```

Comment: I didn’t realize there was an rename function in OS. Does this not work for any cmd built-in function?

Comment: more or less. for instance `dir` is replaced by `os.listdir` or `os.walk`. Also `os.mkdir`, `os.rmdir` plus `shutil` copy/rmtree, etc... It's a bad idea to rely on basic command line tools when python offers the same service, with added portability and reliability